# Error while displaying javadocs in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am trying Jenkins with the help of the book  - "Jenkins - The Definitive Guide"

I am getting error while displaying javadocs:

```
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.2 or 
one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Cannot access central 
(https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) in offline mode and the 
artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.5.2 has 
not been downloaded from it before. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with 
the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, 
please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1]http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
```

Both Java and Maven are installed on the machine where Jenkins is running.

I have the following info from the command line

```
$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.3.9
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_144, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.10.0-32-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Any hint to get around this issue?

--------------------- EDIT ---------------------------

After the last comment I made the changes as suggested and now I got the following errors:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project gameoflife-web: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.wakaleo.gameoflife:gameoflife-
web:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact 
com.wakaleo.gameoflife:gameoflife-core:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1]   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :gameoflife-web
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
Recording test results
Publishing Javadoc
```

Finished: FAILURE

Comment: Check if your jenkins server can access the internet or at least the site https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2

Comment: Try to give manually your maven home directory into Jenkins.
Step1 : Go to Manage Jenkins --> Global tool Configuration 
Step 2: Go to Maven --> Uncheck install automatically.
Step 3: Give your Name in box of Maven. 
Step 4: MAVEN_HOME: /usr/share/maven